# Missing dependency in DTP feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-dtp

I have dependency on some DTP features including org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.lexer. During the build I get error

> Missing requirement: Eclipse Data Tools Platform Lexer Plug-in 1.0.1.v201107221520   (org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.parsers.sql.lexer 1.0.1.v201107221520) requires 'bundle net.sourceforge.lpg.lpgjavaruntime [1.1.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found

When I check target platform I see net.sourceforge.lpg.lpgjavaruntime_1.1.0.v201004271650.jar there, however it's not in p2 repository. How can I satisfy this missing dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to package this plugin in my feature as I couldn't find other feature that was providing it. But clearly this is wrong way to do it.